# Erro ao clicar em Button

Tags: ios, swift

Bom dia!

Estou estudando a linguagem Swift, para iOS e estou com o seguinte problema. Fiz uma aplicação teste, disponibilizada no livro "Swift - Programe para iPhone e iPad" da Casa do Código.

É uma aplicação onde eu coloco um alimento e uma nota para ele, e ao clicar em adicionar, ele vai aparecer na tela em uma lista. O problema é que ao clicar no botão "Adicionar" aparece o seguinte erro, na linha class, no arquivo AppDelegate.swift

> Thread 1: signal SIGBRT

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
```

Segue os códigos:

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var happinessField: UITextField!

@IBAction func add() {
    if nameField == nil || happinessField == nil {
        return
    }

    let name = nameField!.text
    let happiness = Int(happinessField!.text!)
    if happiness == nil {
        return }
    let meal = Meal(name: name!, happiness: happiness!)
    print("eaten: \(meal.name) \(meal.happiness)")

}
}
```

Meal:

```
import Foundation

class Meal {

let name: String
let happiness: Int
var items = Array<Item>()
init(name: String, happiness: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.happiness = happiness
}

func allCalories() -> Double {
    print("Calculating")
    var total = 0.0
    for i in items {
        total += i.calories
    }
    return total
}

}
```

Item:

```
import Foundation

class Item {
let name: String
let calories: Double
init(name: String, calories: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.calories = calories
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o app é inicializado e somente ao clicar no botão acontece o crash, provavelmente o problema está na forma que ação de click do botão foi configurada.

Abra o arquivo storyboard (ou xib se for o caso) e clique com o botão direito na raíz (View Controller). Verique se há alguma conexão com problema, isto é, um triângulo amarelo com uma exclamação. No seu caso o problema deve estar na secão *Received Actions*.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Era isso mesmo.Depois de alguma modificações na organização dos arquivos, deve ter perdido a ligação do código com o botão.